# type deduction fail: shared_ptr of derived template to base template as function argument

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

Here I declared two template classes: A and B, B derives from A:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    int a;
    T t;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    int b;
};
```

And I make a `shared_ptr<B<T>>` and assign it to `shared_ptr<A<T>>`, it's ok:

```
auto b = std::make_shared<B<std::string>>();
std::shared_ptr<A<std::string>> a = b;
```

Here I declared a template function accept `shared_ptr A<T>`:

```
template<typename T>
void proc(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> &a) {
    std::cout << a->a << std::endl;
}
```

it accepts `a` as argument, but rejects `b`:

```
proc<std::string>(a); // OK
proc<std::string>(b); // template argument deduction/substitution failed
                      // cannot convert 'b' (type 'std::shared_ptr<B<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >') to type 'std::shared_ptr<A<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&'
```

I use g++ as compiler with -std=c++11.

This error brings me a lot problems and how could I fix this elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `proc<std::string>(b);`, `b` needs to be converted to `std::shared_ptr<A<std::string>>`. That means a temporary `std::shared_ptr<A<std::string>>` will be constructed and then passed to `proc`. The parameter type of `proc` is an lvalue-reference to non-const, i.e. `std::shared_ptr<A<T>> &`, which can't bind to temporaries.

You can change the parameter type to lvalue-reference to const, which could bind to temporaries. e.g.

```
template<typename T>
void proc(const std::shared_ptr<A<T>> &a) {
//        ^^^^^
    std::cout << a->a << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you make a `shared_ptr` called:

```
auto b = std::make_shared<B<std::string>>();
```

Is of type `std::shared_ptr<B<std::string>>` and,

```
std::shared_ptr<A<std::string>> a = b;
```

Is of type `std::shared_ptr<A<std::string>>`...

In your function parameter, however, you have:

```
void proc(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> &a)
```

Which only points to the `shared_ptr` of **A**, not **B**, so it is **obvious** that **B** won't become **A**...

---

The solution would be to remove the *lvalue* reference of `a` from the function definition, like:

```
void proc(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> a)
```

so, it doesn't refer to **A**, and **B** can easily be converted to **A** during function call...

---

**Edit:** Added an explanation...

**Explanation:**

Remember pointers? from **C**... *yes*, they do the *same function of references*:

```
// Compilable both in C and C++...
int add(int a, int b, int * more_than_3) {
    int const result = a + b;
    if (result > 3)
        *more_than_3 = 1;
    return result;
}
```

Yeah, these which would the function of *pseudo-return types* in C. Like:

```
// Compilable both in C and C++...
int main(void) {
    int more_3;
    int const res = add(2, 3, &more_3);
    printf("Sum of 2 + 3 is %i\n", res);
    if (more_3)
        printf("Given two numbers' sum is more than 3");
}
```

Here, an extra argument is passed which takes the *[address of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) a variable* (*References also do the same thing, they share their address with the variable with whom they are referenced...*)

*Remember*, references and pointers store *the address of another variable inside of them*...

This might be the reason why they made the *address of* operator (`&`) also act for *references* in *C++*...

---

Also, unneeded, but the answer which was posted here by [*@songyuanyao*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679277/type-deduction-fail-shared-ptr-of-derived-template-to-base-template-as-function/53679352#53679352) worked, because:

```
void proc(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> const &a)
```

uses a *constant reference*, a *reference* to a *constant expression*, not a **variable**, so it didn't matter if they mismatched (`A` and `B`)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. Although, I'm still confuesd, why a deduction from `shared_ptr<B>` to `shared_ptr<A> &` is invalid? B is derived from A, so  we can say that B is an A right?

Comment: @forrestJiang Even though they are derived, `A` and `B` are **different classes**, and references are similar to *pointers* in C, and assigning a pointer of different type to another pointer (using *illegal casting*) causes undefined behavior, which, in order to prevent from happening in C++ with references, shows up the error, because it references an instance of `A` not `B`... *Note: C++ would have the same result as C if you use **pointers**, though...*